# Ansible - Combining string with variable to form existing variable

Tags: ansible

Im trying to create some more efficient tasks for upgrading network devices by nesting a variable in another variable so the proper information can be pulled with a single task vs a task for every model, which turns out to be 20+ tasks. I am using the juniper_junos_facts module to pull the model information, in this case the output for junos.model is srx550, then utilize that variable inside of another variable to form model.srx550.path.

vars:

```
model:
  srx550:
    code: 12.3X48-D70.3
    path: "/var/tmp/code/juniper/junos-srxsme-12.3X48-D70.3-domestic.tgz"
```

Playbook:

```
tasks:
  - include_vars:
      file: main.yml

  - name: Log into to Juniper device and determine model with facts module
    juniper_junos_facts:
      host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      user: user
      port: 22
    register: junos

  - debug: msg="{{ ['model.' + junos.model|lower + '.path'] }}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [lab_cpe] => {
    "msg": [
        "model.srx550.path"
```

Expected Output:

```
ok: [lab_cpe] => {
    "msg": [
        "/var/tmp/code/juniper/junos-srxsme-12.3X48-D70.3-domestic.tgz"
```

Any help or guidance on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I saw that last night but it wasnt quite the same as what I was trying to do. I tried to adapt it to what i thought It should be. Im also not sure if registered variables show up under hostvars or not.

None of the following work.
`- debug: msg="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['junos.model'] }}"'`

`- debug: msg="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][model. + 'junos.model' + .path] }}"`

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you.